# Maven archetype `quickstart` fails to expand its POM

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-archetype

In the past when I have used the [`maven-archetype-quickstart`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart) archetype version 1.4 in Maven to create a project within IntelliJ, the initial short POM file automagically expands into a much longer fuller POM file (the trigger for this I've never understood).

Well no more. I am using the EAP (early access) version of IntelliJ 2019.2. Even after doing a Maven `clean` and `install`, the POM is stuck in its original too-short version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>goof</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


</project>
```

I also tried the `Reimport all Maven Projects` button in IntelliJ’s `Maven` panel. But no improvement.

So I have no `src` folder, and no source code files. Doing the Maven `install` results in a couple of mysterious warnings I have not seen:

- Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
- JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!

I have IntelliJ pointing to an external folder for Maven, for the latest Maven 3.6.1. That has never been a problem before.

Is there something I can do with Maven or IntelliJ to make this initial little POM blossom into a full project?

Comment: Sir, are you using Intellij community of ultimate version ? What is the intellij version are you using ?

Comment: Yes, Ultimate edition: `Intellij IDEA 2019.2 EAP (Ultimate edition)` built on 2019-05-31. Perhaps this is a bug related to this early-access version of IntelliJ. But jeez, what a basic feature to be broken: Creating a new basic Maven project — therefore I assume there is some other issue.

Comment: Sir, you can try like this. Go to File Menu, Invalidate Caches/Restart and then go to Maven and click on Reimport All Maven Project.

Comment: @Sambit Thanks, but no help. I tried the invalidate and restart. But when I do the Maven `clean` and `install`, I get the same two warnings, and the POM is still not automagically expanded into a full POM.

Comment: Sir, you can try one last thing, First close the Intellij Idea and then in your user directory in Windows 10, could please try to delete the folder/s related to .IntelliJIdea<year>.<version>? Next you open Intellij Idea and it will be started like a new setup and you can create a maven project.

Comment: There is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211628